# Android action bar searchview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-search

Hi i need create searchView from my array like in the image below.
[image]

My code:

Top_meny.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/paieska"
          android:title="search_title"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

FirstClass.java

```
public class FirstClass extends FragmentActivity implements OnQueryTextListener{

     ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                test.add("a");
                test.add("b");

     }

     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu);
        SearchView paieska = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.paieska).getActionView();
        paieska.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;

    }
}
```

and who next? how to short and add to searchView?

Answer (score 0):

something same as this

```
MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActionBar().getThemedContext());
item.setActionView(sv);
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
        | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reader, menu);
return true;
```

add to `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Just changed the indendation. :)